# in which location cronjob for root can be set

Tags: cron

I run this command

```
cat /var/log/syslog|grep 'something'
```

and get result like

```
Mar  6 11:10:01 ip-xxx-31-xx-xx CRON[25527]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/node something.cron.js )
```

This `something.cron` is run in every hour. But i can't see it in `crontab` of `root` user and also not in `/etc/cron.hourly`. Where else cronjob can be set in ubuntu14.04?

Comment: In `/etc/crontab` itself or `/etc/cron.d` as well.

Comment: [Useless use of `cat`](http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html#cat).

Comment: Does it run at the same time as cron.hourly, or at a different time?

Answer (score 3):

- If you want to search for a pattern in all *system* crontab files you can run:

  ```
  grep -e <PATTERN> /etc/crontab /etc/cron.d/*
  ```
- If you want to search the crontab file of the *current user* use:

  ```
  crontab -l | grep -e <PATTERN>
  ```
- If you want to search the crontab file of a *different user* use:

  ```
  sudo crontab -u <USERNAME> -l | grep -e <PATTERN>
  ```
- If you want to search *system and per-user* crontab files you can join the two, e. g.:

  ```
  crontab -l | grep -e <PATTERN> /etc/crontab /etc/cron.d/* -
  ```

  (`-` tells `grep` to read from standard input in addition to other listed files.)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the Crontab in /etc/crontab.
If you want to list down all the crontab scheduled, you can type crontab -l